# When I start playing on the Technic launcher, the playable screen is small even in fullscreen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-pixelmon

When I start playing on the Technic launcher, the playable screen is small even in fullscreen. How do I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please help me with this problem its really annoying but it only happens on the Technic Launcher and i tried to uninstall it and reinstall it Please Help Me

Comment: Have you changed the settings to scale the GUI?

Comment: Wheres that setting??

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10390), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/10568), [What exactly is technical support?](//meta.arqade.com/q/11015) and [Update the off-topic reason for "Technical support for non-vanilla Minecraft"…](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13542), only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. It's not off-topic if the game runs fine without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix. Simply go to the Settings > Video Settings, and click on the "GUI Scale" button. this will alternate between Small, Medium, Large, and Auto. Choose the setting that best fits what you want.